# How to set a 5 minute interval on the nativescript-datetimepicker plugin?

Tags: angular, nativescript

I'm creating a Nativescript app where employees of a restaurant can fill in how many hours they've worked. Currently I'm using the nativescript-datetimepicker plugin (https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-datetimepicker). I get how to set the format and locale properties but I'm unable to set an interval on the minutes. I want the users to only be able to pick :00, :05, :10... Where do I start?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm afraid I still don't get how to alter the minute picker...

Comment: I don't think it's possible with this plugin, you may have to write a custom TimePicker widget extending [TimePickerDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog) on Android. For iOS, you may simply set the [minuteInterval](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker/1615998-minuteinterval?language=objc) on [nativeTimePicker](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-datetimepicker/blob/master/src/datetimepicker.ios.ts#L33) AKA `UIDatePicker`.